# Unable to access web app from outside docker container

Tags: docker

I have an ASP.Net Core web application running inside a container.

Docker for MacOS: 1.12.3
Container IP: 172.17.0.2

```
docker run -it -p 6000:6000 -v $(pwd):/workspace microsoft/dotnet:latest
```

which listens on http://*:6000

i'm able to curl the following from within the container & i'm getting the desired response.

```
curl http://localhost:6000 or curl http://172.17.0.2:6000
```

however, when i try to access the site from outside the container (on my MacOS) that's when i don't get any output.

Why am i unable to access from outside the container?

Answer (score 0):

It was the port number, changed it and it worked.

Comment: what is was the exact issue